# Resource file in ASP.NET MVC app renders strange letters

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some odd situation. However, when I want to translate to Serbian culture (I just copied some text in GlobalRes.sr.resx file) it shows me like this:
[image]
I have problem with those letters which are not standardised like: ČčĆćŠšĐžžć

this is my html:

```
<h3 class="title">
                            Ostvarite 10% popusta <br> kada rezervišete direktno preko naše stranice
                        </h3>
```

I copied translations from Google Translate..maybe that is a problem?

Comment: Just a guess but are you using a custom font? Maybe the one you're using doesn't support those characters and is falling back to a default? Or that's the way the font displays the letters. Does changing the font make a difference? Does using the html code for the letters change anything? It should be `&scaron;`

Comment: @mboldt yup, now I checked Roboto font does not have those special chars. How can I add them? or how to find Roboto font with latin extendeed chars?

Comment: sorry I can't help you with that. If they were simply not included in the font then you might be out of luck.